# How compiler evaluates arguments to empty function?

Tags: c++, optimization, compilation, compiler-optimization

I'm wondering how compiler optimization handles the evaluation of parameters in case a function is an empty call. Have an example:

```
void function(const std::string& input) {}
std::string getInput()
{
// some magic here...
return "some_string";
}

int main()
{
function(getInput());

return 0;
}
```

In such case if `function()` is an empty call, will compiler optimize that in such way that the call to `getInput()` won't happen?

Comment: Why not simply look at the compiled code for yourself and see exactly what it does?

Comment: the code will not be optimized out, `getInput` may have some side effect. You can try yourself with a display in your `getInput`

Comment: @MartinMorterol that really depends. It is going to be optimized if there are no side effects: https://godbolt.org/z/W4hGbf6n6

Comment: @RemyLebeau Reading compiled code may not be "simple" depending of the level of the user ;)

Comment: OP, are you concerned by the performance of your code (will the compiler make a `call` to the function) or the correctness of the code (will the code make what you think it will make) ?

Comment: Standard FAQ entry for all questions asking if a compiler can/will do an optimization: [What exactly is the "as-if" rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718262/what-exactly-is-the-as-if-rule) If an optimization falls under this rule, and if the situation is easy to recognize, then there is probably a compiler that does it.

Comment: If you understand assembler then you could use the compiler explorer at https://godbolt.org/ to see what the code does under various compilers.
Using the Microsoft C++ compiler it is optimized away as far as I can tell when optimizations are enabled and not when they aren't (no surprise there)

Comment: compiler maybe inlined some short and simple functions by itself when it optimize code,  so your empty function maybe "disappeared" in compiled output.

Comment: @MartinMorterol I'm concerned about the performance of my code. But as some of the guys suggested here, I will look into compiler explorer to see what's happening.

Comment: Except for the sake of asking the question, is there a reason to write such a function ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust yeah, there is a reason. I wanted to have a class method that serializes class to a string that could be passed to the logger.

Comment: You can make the string a static class member.

Answer (score 0):

Other than return-value optimization, C++ doesn't allow optimizations that change visible side effects of the program.  ([What are copy elision and return value optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization)).  e.g. a `cout <<` in a constructor might not get called, or in more recent C++ versions is guaranteed not to get called in some cases where you'd naively expect it (and where earlier C++ revisions would make that side effect happen).

This isn't that, so the call to `getInput()` definitely has to happen, even if its return value ends up not being used (because it inlines and optimizes away `void function(const std::string& input) {}`).  The fact that `getInput()`'s return value is being passed to an empty function makes zero difference in the call to `getInput()` itself.

As a general rule, only visible side effects in constructors / destructors are ever in danger of being optimized away.  It's normally a bad idea to put visible side effects in constructors, *except* for side effects on the object being constructed.  Except for debug logging where you *want* it to not log depending on optimization.